# How to toggle aframe marker detection

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm developing a page for mobile that uses aframe. It needs to switch between displaying simple DOM things and displaying the video feed along with the overlayed 3D content.

While users are just viewing the DOM elements I'd like to turn off any aframe marker detection (to save on processing).

Also, I don't want to turn on/off the camera since I don't want users to keep getting a prompt that allows camera access.